# How to fail a spring job if exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which converts tsv file to json. I have specified the following listener which checks for exit code:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;

public class StepResultListener implements StepExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("Called beforeStep().");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("Called afterStep().");
        String exitCode = stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode();
        if (exitCode.equals("FAILED")){
            return ExitStatus.FAILED;
        }
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

I want to fail the the whole job if the step fails:

```
@Bean
    public Step stepOne(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider webIdProvider) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepOne")
                .<WebTaxonomy, WebTaxonomy> chunk(10)
                .reader(readerWeb())
                .processor(processorWeb(mapper, webIdProvider))
                .writer(writerWeb(mapper))
                .listener(new StepResultListener())
                .build();
    }
```

However it still proceeds to complete the job. Any ideas how I can achieve this ?

this is my batch configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private static final String OUTPUT_DATA_JSON = "target/web_taxonomy.json";
    private static final String OUTPUT_DATA_APP_JSON = "target/app_taxonomy.json";


    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<WebTaxonomy> readerWeb() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<WebTaxonomy>()
                .name("webTaxonomyItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("/web_taxonomy.tsv"))
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .lineMapper(lineMapperWeb()).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultLineMapper<WebTaxonomy> lineMapperWeb() {
        DefaultLineMapper<WebTaxonomy> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizerWeb());
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<WebTaxonomy>() {
            {
                setTargetType(WebTaxonomy.class);
            }
        });
        return lineMapper;
    }


    @Bean
    public DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizerWeb() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB);
        tokenizer.setNames("taxonomy_id", "website_name", "brand_name", "publisher", "category", "category_2",
                "category_3", "category_4", "category_5", "curated", "blacklist", "brand_1", "brand_2", "brand_3",
                "brand_4", "brand_5", "brand_6", "regex", "host", "source", "creation_date");
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("webIdProvider")
    @Bean
    public WebTaxonomyItemProcessor processorWeb(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider webIdProvider) {
        Map<String, Long> webMapping = getMapping(mapper, "src/main/resources/web_taxonomy.json", "taxonomy_id", "website_name");
        Long maxID = Collections.max(webMapping.values());
        webIdProvider.setID(maxID);
        return new WebTaxonomyItemProcessor(webMapping, webIdProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepOne(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider webIdProvider) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepOne")
                .<WebTaxonomy, WebTaxonomy> chunk(10)
                .reader(readerWeb())
                .processor(processorWeb(mapper, webIdProvider))
                .writer(writerWeb(mapper))
                .listener(new StepResultListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<WebTaxonomy> writerWeb(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<WebTaxonomy>()
                .name("WebTaxonomyJsonFileItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(OUTPUT_DATA_JSON))
                .lineAggregator(new JsonLineAggregator<>(mapper))
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Job updateWebTaxonomy(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider webIdProvider) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("updateWebTaxonomy")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepOne(mapper, webIdProvider))
                .build();
    }

    // App job

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<AppTaxonomy> readerApp() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<AppTaxonomy>()
                .name("appTaxonomyItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("/app_taxonomy.tsv"))
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .lineMapper(lineMapperApp()).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultLineMapper<AppTaxonomy> lineMapperApp() {
        DefaultLineMapper<AppTaxonomy> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizerApp());
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<AppTaxonomy>() {
            {
                setTargetType(AppTaxonomy.class);
            }
        });
        return lineMapper;
    }


    @Bean
    public DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizerApp() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB);
        tokenizer.setNames("taxonomy_id", "app_name", "app_store", "app_package_name", "brand_name",
                "publisher", "category", "category_2", "category_3", "category_4", "category_5", "blacklist", "brand_1",
                "brand_2", "brand_3", "brand_4", "brand_5", "brand_6", "platform", "source", "creation_date");
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("appIdProvider")
    @Bean
    public AppTaxonomyItemProcessor processorApp(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider appIDProvider) {
        Map<String, Long> appMapping = getMapping(mapper,"src/main/resources/app_taxonomy.json", "taxonomy_id", "app_package_name");
        Long maxID = Collections.max(appMapping.values());
        appIDProvider.setID(maxID);
        return new AppTaxonomyItemProcessor(appMapping, appIDProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepTwo(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider appIDProvider) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepTwo")
                .<AppTaxonomy, AppTaxonomy> chunk(10)
                .reader(readerApp())
                .processor(processorApp(mapper, appIDProvider))
                .writer(writerApp(mapper))
                .listener(new StepResultListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<AppTaxonomy> writerApp(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<AppTaxonomy>()
                .name("AppTaxonomyJsonFileItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(OUTPUT_DATA_APP_JSON))
                .lineAggregator(new JsonLineAggregator<>(mapper))
                .build();

    }
    @Bean
    public Job updateAppTaxonomy(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider appIDProvider) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("updateAppTaxonomy")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepTwo(mapper, appIDProvider))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager batchTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(15);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(30);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher batchJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor()); // Or below line
        // jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator(JobRegistry jobRegistry) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(batchJobLauncher());
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobOperator;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

    public void run1(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider appIDProvider) {
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
        try {
            batchJobLauncher().run(updateAppTaxonomy(mapper, appIDProvider), jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }


    public void run2(ObjectMapper mapper, IdProvider webIdProvider) {
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
        try {
            batchJobLauncher().run(updateWebTaxonomy(mapper, webIdProvider), jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public Map<String, Long> getMapping(ObjectMapper mapper, String path, String id, String value){

        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(currentLine);
                long taxonomyID = node.get(id).longValue();
                String key = node.get(value).textValue().toLowerCase();
                map.put(key, taxonomyID);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;

    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want it to do? to fail the 'complete job', or to complete the job? those two things don't really match up

Comment: so if I understand correctly if it return FAILED exit code it should fail the job

Comment: By default, even without that listener, if the step fails, the job will fail as well, unless you have defined a custom flow. Can you share your job flow definition? Or even better, a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: I have edited my question to include batch configuration

Comment: If this code represents a job in a scheduling system, when an exception is thrown (assuming you are throwing an exception when the job fails) to tell the scheduler it failed, do a System.exit(1).  The 1 is the error code.  Anything non-zero is an error code.  By default System.exit(0) is always called when a job completes.  Of course that Sysetem.exit(1) will be when you catch your exception.  By the way, also in your exception, you may want to log very specific information to help the person who is debugging it why it failed.  Log data that is being processed...etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the example. Your steps are simple (ie non fault-tolerant) chunk-oriented steps, so I a said in my previous comment, the job should fail as soon as the first step fails. That listener has no added value. What you can do is get a handle on the `JobExecution` when you run your job in `run1` method, and inspect it when it finishes to see its status, then exit your JVM as needed with the correct exit code. something like: `JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters()); if (jobExecution.getStatus().isUnsuccessful()) System.exit(1);`